# Spring - How to write file to classpath?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, classpath

I'm trying to write a new file to a location specific to my class path.

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("TEST-1.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

How can I specify "TEST-1.xls" so that the path is relative to the class path of my spring project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, a "Classpath" may consist of multiple path entries. In fact, most Classpaths do. In that case, you'd need to conclude (somehow) which Classpath entry you're referring to.

In other words, the phrase "a location specific to my classpath" isn't quite "legitimate" given the semantics of what a Classpath is. Compare this to your operating system's `PATH` setting. If I asked you to write a file to a location "specific to your `PATH` setting", what would you do?

Comment: Also consider that the classpath may not include ANY writable directories... the entries could be jars inside a WAR file or a set of network URLs.  In general it is not safe to treat anything in the classpath as writable.

Comment: "if I asked you to write a file to a location 'specific to your PATH setting', what would you do?" I would read the $PATH environment variable, parse it, look for anywhere which looks writeable and fairly generic (/usr/local/bin, not /opt/my-application/bin) and write there.  How do I do *that* with the classpath, which might not be set via an environment variable but rather via a system property or VM switch?